# No trait information (runtime warning)

Tags: swift, xcode, ios9, ipod

I wanted to test my app on my **iPod** **6th** generation `(iOS 9)` but it gives me this warning (in Assets.xcassets)

```
No trait information for iPod "7,1"
```

I have no idea what is going on. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is the first time i've heard of such warning. Please add a detailed description of this for better understanding.

Comment: That's pretty much it. even i haven't heard of this warning :D here's the full story : i've been working on the app for a few weeks and when iOS 9 came out, i updated my iPod so that i could run my app on it. it works fine but it gives me this warning(in Assets.xcassets folder). i really don't know what is going on.

Comment: Actually not much details... It's just a warning says that "No trait information for iPhone8,4" when I connected my iPhone SE.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same warning for a project after connecting the new 10.5" iPad: `.../Assets.xcassets: No trait information for "iPad7,4"`. This seems to happen when your device is more recent than the installed Xcode version that is Xcode didn't know about any new iPads and their specs yet. After manually updating Xcode to the latest version the warning was gone.